# Format Text Field To Date In Access Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form in Access that has two text boxes that are format to be a short date.  I am now attempting to capture those values and use in a query in the `WHERE` clause.  I tried this syntax

```
Between CDate([Forms]![Form1]![date1]) And CDate([Forms]![Form1]![date2])
```

> This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is to complex to be evaluated.  For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements.  Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables.

How should I capture & convert the entries from my form text boxes so that I can use them in my query?

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue, works for me. If you want to provide db for review, I recommend Box.com fileshare site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the parameters to free Access from guessing, then use these "as is":

```
Parameters
    [Forms]![Form1]![date1] DateTime,
    [Forms]![Form1]![date2] DateTime;
Select 
    <your select statement>
From 
    <your table/query>
Where
    [YourDateField] Between 
        [Forms]![Form1]![date1] And 
        [Forms]![Form1]![date2]
```